# Getting array of data in android from mysql json using volley

Tags: android, mysql, wamp, android-volley

I am populating listview with separate item file with json string here...

item file is ticket_items
listview file is ticktsfr

Tickets.php:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

$user_id  = $_GET['user_id'];
require_once('db_configuration.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.event_name, b.ticket_name,b.ticket_quantity,
b.ticket_description, b.ticket_channel, b.ticket_start_date,
b.ticket_end_date,b.user_id FROM event a, ticket b WHERE a.event_id =
b.event_id and a.user_id = b.user_id) AS T WHERE user_id='"$user_id"'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
array_push($result,array
(
"event_name"=>$row[0],
"ticket_name"=>$row[1],
"ticket_quantity"=>$row[2],
"ticket_description"=>$row[3],
"ticket_channel"=>$row[4],
"ticket_start_date"=>$row[5],
"ticket_end_date"=>$row[6],
"user_id"=>$row[7]
)
);
}
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Tickets.java:(Activity)

```
public class Tickets extends Fragment {
//boolean variable to check user is logged in or not
//initially it is false
boolean loggedIn = false;
private ListView listView;

private static final String JSON_URL =
"http://myip/eevento/tickets.php?user_id=";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ticketsfr, null);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list3);

    sendRequest();
    return view;
}

private void sendRequest(){

    String url = JSON_URL+Loginhandler.USER_ID;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json) {
    Ticketshandler2 pj = new Ticketshandler2(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
        Ticketshandler cl = new Ticketshandler(getActivity(),
Ticketshandler2.event_name, Ticketshandler2.ticket_name,
Ticketshandler2.ticket_quantity, Ticketshandler2.ticket_description,
Ticketshandler2.ticket_channel, Ticketshandler2.ticket_start_date,
Ticketshandler2.ticket_end_date, Ticketshandler2.user_id);
        listView.setAdapter(cl);

}
}
```

Ticketshandler.java:(Class)

```
public class Ticketshandler extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
TextView namme;

ProgressDialog loading;



private String[] event_name;
private String[] ticket_name;
private String[] ticket_quantity;
private String[] ticket_description;
private String[] ticket_channel;
private String[] ticket_start_date;
private String[] ticket_end_date;
private String[] user_id;
private Activity context;

public Ticketshandler(Activity context, String[] event_name, String[]
ticket_name,String[] ticket_quantity,String[] ticket_description,String[]
ticket_channel,String[] ticket_start_date,String[] ticket_end_date,String[]
user_id) {
    super(context, R.layout.tickets_item, event_name);
    this.context = context;
    this.event_name = event_name;
    this.ticket_name = ticket_name;
    this.ticket_quantity = ticket_quantity;
    this.ticket_description = ticket_description;
    this.ticket_channel = ticket_channel;
    this.ticket_start_date = ticket_start_date;
    this.ticket_end_date = ticket_end_date;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tickets_item, null, true);
    TextView event_topic_description = (TextView)
listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.titem);

    String output = "" + event_name[position] + "\n" + ticket_name[position]
+ "\n" + ticket_quantity[position] + "\n" + ticket_description[position] +
"\n"
+ ticket_channel[position] + "\n" + ticket_start_date[position] + "\n" +
ticket_end_date[position];
 //   String output = "" +event_name[position];
       event_topic_description.setText(output);
    System.out.println(output);

        return listViewItem;
}
```

}

Ticketshandler2.java:(Class)

```
public class Ticketshandler2 {
public static String[] event_name;
public static String[] ticket_name;
public static String[] ticket_quantity;
public static String[] ticket_description;
public static String[] ticket_channel;
public static String[] ticket_start_date;
public static String[] ticket_end_date;
public static String[] user_id;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String EVENT_NAME = "event_name";
public static final String TICKET_NAME = "ticket_name";
public static final String TICKET_QUANTITY = "ticket_quantity";
public static final String TICKET_DESCRIPTION = "ticket_description";
public static final String TICKET_CHANNEL = "ticket_channel";
public static final String TICKET_START_DATE = "ticket_start_date";
public static final String TICKET_END_DATE = "ticket_end_date";
public static final String USER_ID = "user_id";

private JSONArray users = null;

private String json;

public Ticketshandler2(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        System.out.println(users);
        event_name = new String[users.length()];
        ticket_name = new String[users.length()];
        ticket_quantity = new String[users.length()];
        ticket_description = new String[users.length()];
        ticket_channel = new String[users.length()];
        ticket_start_date = new String[users.length()];
        ticket_end_date = new String[users.length()];
        user_id = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
             JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                event_name[i] = jo.getString(EVENT_NAME);
                ticket_name[i] = jo.getString(TICKET_NAME);
                ticket_quantity[i] = jo.getString(TICKET_QUANTITY);
                ticket_description[i] = jo.getString(TICKET_DESCRIPTION);
                ticket_channel[i] = jo.getString(TICKET_CHANNEL);
                ticket_start_date[i] = jo.getString(TICKET_START_DATE);
                ticket_end_date[i] = jo.getString(TICKET_END_DATE);
                user_id[i] = jo.getString(USER_ID);

            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 
}
```

Log:

```
"12-09 12:00:17.750 31591-31591/com.example.dell.evento W/System.err:
org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be
converted to JSONObject"
```

I think my query has some issues, but it is working perfectly in wamp mysql separately..I dont understand what is the issue,, help...

Comment: First check what response you are actually getting from the server.

Comment: Response: {"result":[{"event_name":"evento","ticket_name":"RSVP","ticket_quantity":"12","ticket_description":"test","ticket_channel":"test","ticket_start_date":"2015-11-03 06:03:42 PM","ticket_end_date":"2015-11-03 06:03:42 PM","user_id":"80"}]}

Comment: That's a valid json!

Comment: Help me man...:/ @PareshMayani

Comment: Is this the response you are actually getting in activity code?

Comment: No this is from php code, in activity its not printing @PareshMayani

Comment: Debug it and then check whether you are actually getting desired response. Then actually you should move for JSON parsing things!

Answer (score 0):

Your response code might be not escape from htmlentities.
you need to first escape html string to proper character code.because java default not took any character code.

Comment: Here is the response: {"result":[{"event_name":"evento","ticket_name":"RSVP","ticket_quantity":"12","ticket_description":"test","ticket_channel":"test","ticket_start_date":"2015-11-03 06:03:42 PM","ticket_end_date":"2015-11-03 06:03:42 PM","user_id":"80"}]}